# fcgid configuration breaks Apache

Tags: httpd.conf, mod-fcgid

I'm trying to include the following block of code on my site in order to run a fast-cgi script:

```
# Create a directory for the iipsrv binary
ScriptAlias /fcgi-bin/ "/home/USERNAME/SITENAME/fcgi-bin/"

# Set the options on that directory
<Directory "/home/USERNAME/SITENAME/fcgi-bin/">
   AllowOverride None
   Options None
 # Syntax for access is different in Apache 2.4 - uncomment appropriate version
   Apache 2.2
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

   Apache 2.4
    Require all granted

 # Set the module handler
   AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
</Directory>

# Set our environment variables for the IIP server
FcgidInitialEnv VERBOSITY "5"
FcgidInitialEnv LOGFILE "/home/USERNAME/SITENAME/fcgi-bin/iipsrv.log"
FcgidInitialEnv MAX_IMAGE_CACHE_SIZE "10"
FcgidInitialEnv JPEG_QUALITY "50"
FcgidInitialEnv MAX_CVT "3000"

# Define the idle timeout as unlimited and the number of # processes we want
FcgidIdleTimeout 0
FcgidMaxClassProcessesPerClass 1
```

When I add this code and restart my server all of my sites quit working.  I obviously don't have it configured right and I don't know enough about fast-cgi to know what I'm doing wrong.  If someone could point out to me what the problem may be and suggest some fixes I'd appreciate it.  The support folks at my hosting provider (Dreamhost, on a VPS) will not support custom configurations so I'm hammering at this on my own.

Answer (score 0):

To start with:

```
Apache 2.2
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all

Apache 2.4
  Require all granted
```

Pick one or the other AND neither the `Apache 2.2` nor the `Apache 2.4` line should be uncommented.

Comment: Correcting for that (on Apache 2.2) still ends up with the same problem -- all of the sites stop working when this configuration is included.

Comment: can you run a config test, perhaps (depending on install) with script `apachectl -t`